# What was a turf rick in Ireland, circa 1833?

Tags: 19th-century, ireland, newspapers, 1830s

I was reading old newspapers when I came across this:

[image: Pg.2,Cl.1, 10 January 1833 Southern Reporter and Cork Commercial Courier]

The bit I am wondering about is the part that says "was at a turf rick for some turf". Googling "turf rick", brings up a bunch of landscapers named Rick. Also, I don't think this is traditional turf, because I think that would be an unaffordable, not to mention useless (you need every acre for food, not grass), luxury.

Comment: Well now I need to know what happened Saturday night

Comment: @BurnsBA Initially, I was going to edit the answer, but now I think I am going to do a Q&A on the incident. I will update you when I post it, but for now, just know that it was 3 men who were killed by police on 05 January 1833 in Kanturk, County Cork, Ireland. This article was the coroner's inquest. Look up "Tithe War" on Wikipedia for some background information.

Comment: This is the answer I did on what happened at this incident, later dubbed the Kanturk Massacre.: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/69572/what-was-the-kanturk-massacre-thernagree-affray/69573#69573

Comment: The Dutch word for peat is ... turf.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer to this while trying some other Google searches before posting my question. The answer is that "turf" is actually [peat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peat), which was the primary source of fuel in Ireland at the time, used in cooking and heating. There were even [peat-powered locomotives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CI%C3%89_No._CC1#Turf_as_locomotive_fuel). Today, there is at least [one company](https://www.nature.com/articles/063590a0#:%7E:text=At%20the%20Karpalund%20sugar%20refinery%20peat%20is%20now%20solely%20used%20for%20the%20nine%20boilers%20in%20use%20there%20of%20100%20horse%2Dpower%20each) that still uses peat in powering their boilers. [In Ireland](https://turfmagazine.com/the-latest/the-irish-turf-controversy/#:%7E:text=In%20Ireland%20the%20word%20%E2%80%9Cturf,found%20in%20peatlands%2C%20or%20bogs.), the term "turf" still refers to the peat so prevalent in the country. The word, "rick" is used in the definition Google gives as "a stack of hay, corn, straw, or similar material, especially one formerly built into a regular shape and thatched." So, the answer is that a "turf rick" is a large pile of peat used for heating purposes.

Comment: Firewood (at least around here) still is usually purchased in units of ricks.

Comment: @T.E.D. here it's sold in cubic metres or in cords - which amount to 128 cu feet or 4'x4'x8'

Comment: @T.E.D., how big is a rick of firewood?

Comment: @JimmyG. - Usually 4x1x8. 4 ricks to a cord. A cord is a LOT of wood though. If you're mostly just using your fireplace for social/asthetic reasons, you won't go through even a single rick in a winter. Most people I know just order a half or quarter rick.

Comment: The point of putting turf (peat) and hay in ricks is that is needs to dry before you can do anything with it. Turf ricks may stand for a few months before they get brought home.

Comment: Another unit of measure of firewood is a face cord. That's 4'x8' by one log length (often 16-20 inches). It's used interchangeably with rick.

Comment: Probably relevant: https://www.etymonline.com/word/rick#etymonline_v_15041

Comment: @T.E.D. in some states, it's illegal to sell firewood by the "rick".  Only selling by the "cord" is permitted.  Even "face cord" is illegal. https://law.justia.com/codes/connecticut/2013/title-43/chapter-752/section-43-27/

Comment: Seeing this question on a History site confused and amused me, because turf ricks are an everyday feature of this part of the world.

Comment: @DavePhD - That looks like a deceptive advertising law. Notice in my comment I said "Usually". Some people make "ricks" different sizes. It looks like that wiggle room is CT's problem with the unit. I suppose they could have insisted any advertised rick is a specific volume, but insisting on the better-defined "cord" seems easier to codify.

Comment: These ricks seem to be cognate with _rigs_, as in ‘[corn](https://www.wordnik.com/words/corn-rig) [rigs](https://terreceltiche.altervista.org/corn-rigs-are-bonnie/)’.

Comment: @gidds - From what I read there, I don't know about that. Their "rigs" seem more of a 2-dimensional concept than a 3, and its talking about unharvested cereal grain patches, not harvested stacks of drying matter. Probably has more in common with the "rig" in "oil rig". Interesting read though.

Comment: @mcalex  The turfs are cut vertically with a spade with a 90 degree fold up the middle, and 18 inches long. So one turf is about 18 x 5 x 5 inches, with a small square of grass and moss at one end (the peat bog is essentially dead moss). Rolling them would break them up. When dry, they shrink slightly and are used just like wooden logs. One of my friends cut enough turf between ages 12 and 18 to pay his way through Trinity College, Dublin.